# Where to begin if I want to implement a RDMA NIC driver - Suggestions

Tags: linux, unix, driver, nic, rdma

Really appreciate the wonderful and very helpful community here. Need help understanding where to begin.
My task is to understand and write device drivers for RDMA over Converged Ethernet.

My problem is that I don't know where to start. I have access to the vendor's PRM and sample source code.

This is the first time I am involved in this kind of task.

Should I begin reading and understanding the Specs and sample source code for the following before I begin with RDMA

1. PCI
2. PCI Express
3. NIC(Ethenet)

I tried reading the RDMA PRM, but it seems like I am unable to understand clearly. I was thinking maybe because I don't understand PCI(Express), NIC well enough, I am having a hard time.

What do you suggest? 
Please help me with your valuable suggestions. Would be really thankful to you all!

Comment: Windows, Linux, BSD/FreeBSD, VMWare, AIX, etc? Is it some new NIC from a vendor that haven't done an RDMA-capable NICs before? 
Notice that you have full drivers for various RDMA-capable NICs as part of OFED (OpenFabrics Enterprise Distribution)

Comment: Thanks kliteyn yeah..it's from a vendor who don't have drivers for vmware...i would like to understand how does one go about tackling such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look the OFED stack. They usually provide the RDMA driver for most RDMA-enabled NIC cards.